# selecting second string point using js substring

Tags: javascript

i want to select a sting from the long para. it has number of dot('.')s. i want to trim the word from the second one, is it any way to do this?

example

```
var name = "one.two.three";
name.substring(0,name.indexOf('.'))
name.substring(0,name.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

from above trimming in case if i use indexOf it gives first word (one), if i use lastIndex of it gives the word (three), but i need to select the second one, to get value as 'second'

how can i trim this using indexOf method? or to select multicombination strings like one.three or one.two, or two.three?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var name="one.two.three";
var result=name.split(".").slice(0,2).join(".");
```

Example:

```
"".split(".").slice(0,2).join(".") // return ""
"one".split(".").slice(0,2).join(".") // return "one"
"one.two".split(".").slice(0,2).join(".") // return "one.two"
"one.two.three".split(".").slice(0,2).join(".") // return "one.two"
"one.two.three.four.five".split(".").slice(0,2).join(".") // return "one.two"
```

Answer (score 4):

use string.split.

e.g.

```
name.split(".")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that work for you ?

```
var name = "one.two.three";
var params = name.split('.');
console.log(params[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var name = "one.two.three";

var output = name.split('.');

alert(output[1]);
```

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/af3QD/)